# how to force redirect HTTP to HTTPS Kubernetes Service for AWS EKS

Tags: kubernetes, https, devops, amazon-eks

I have set up an EKS cluster in that I have 3 apps deployed I right now its working fine with SSL certificate and I just only want it to force redirect user's HTTP requests to HTTPS I have tried many ways doing it with different services and ingress controller but none of them is working. Please help me out on this if you know of any solutions for this.

Thank you in advance...
here is the link to the service.yaml. I am using right now.

https://gist.github.com/vyasishanatc194/a01c2bda288c908e4c5c7c45f98ecb41

Comment: Have you tried configuring your LB to do it for you? https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elb-redirect-http-to-https-using-alb/

Comment: you tried many ways but could you please explain here which one currently you are running ? so out of many solution it would be better to suggest to optimal easy solution. how you have exposed your multiple apps, which LB type you are using to expose app and current setup of ssl.

Comment: hello, Harsh thank you for your response please check out this link for the current service I am using .https://gist.github.com/vyasishanatc194/a01c2bda288c908e4c5c7c45f98ecb41

Comment: @RakeshGupta Yes i have tried creating ALB but its not creating I don't know why. i can create it manually with AWS console but with the API I am not able to create one